# How to write a formula to number a column when another column contains a certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to label a column with component numbers if column A has a certain value.
Component 1, 2, 3 would be used for each number in column A, but would reset to 1 every time a new number is in column A.  See below:

```
In column A  In Column B      In Column C (what I want...currently blank..)
1222             x             Component 1
1222             xx            Component 2
1222             xxx           Component 3
1222             xxxx          Component 4
1222             xxxb          Component 5
1223             x             Component 1
1223             xxd           Component 2 
1224             r             Component 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
="Component "&COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)
```

[image: SO33441906 example]

Comment: Yes this is much cleaner. I've removed mine.

Comment: Column B is the component I need to number in column c

Comment: Your formula doesn't reset as the item number in column A changes, so that won't work.  If Column A is the item number and Column B is the component part number, column C should be numbering the component pieces for column B, related to column A's part number.